# Sonarqube timemachine API and metrics characteristics

Tags: rest, sonarqube, metrics

Is there a way to retrieve the characteristic of a metric of a project over time? For instance TESTABILITY is a characteristic of the metric "squale_index". Squale Index can be retrieved for each project using the /api/timemachine interface. However I could not find a reference to filter it in the api documentation. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

i've asked a similar question about the technical debt pyramid, that show debt by charasteristic and here is the answer:

[sonarqube how to access to default technical debt pyramid values from web service api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310373/sonarqube-how-to-access-to-default-technical-debt-pyramid-values-from-web-servic)

i think that the only way to access to these information its using the payed plugin (sqale).