# sonarqube how to access to default technical debt pyramid values from web service api?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

Im trying to access to default technical debt pyramid values, the chart that appears on dashboard, using the web service api that sonarqube provide.

I don't have SQALE plugin installed, i just need those default values.

there is any way to access to these values using the web service api?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Values in the technical debt pyramid was the amont of technical debt for each characteristics. 
As characteristics have been [removed](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7364) in SonarQube 5.5, I would not recommend you to try to use theses values.

If you need technical debt values per type for instance, you can use the [api/issues/search WS](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/web_api/api/issues/search) using parameters 'facetMode=effort' and 'facets=types'.

Comment: api/issues/search is giving me 1st project's complete technical debt data along with date and time. How can I get the same for all projects?

Comment: @HarshaBiyani, api/issues/search is a paginated WS, so you need to browse next pages to access other projects. But I would recommend you to execute the WS on only one project at a time (with the 'projectKeys' parameter set to one project), and to re-execute it for each projects.

Comment: could you please give me URL pattern after appending projectKeys?

Comment: Simply put the key of your project, for instance ...&projectKeys=org.sonarsource.sonarqube%3Asonarqube (for issues on SonarQube project)

Comment: You're welcome ! It's good to know that you're now able to move forward on your needs.